# lando - configured database not showing in phpmyadmin

Tags: docker, lando

I have installed Drupal8 in Lando https://docs.lando.dev/
I have added phpmyAdmin service in lando file problem is that configured database not showing in phpmyAdmin.

```
name: mydrupal8
recipe: drupal8
config:
  webroot: /drupal


services: # Define your services
  appserver:  # Create a web server container
    type: php:7.2 # Specify what version of php to use
    via: apache   # This could be nginx, should you choose so
    webroot: www  # Specify webroot
    config:  # If you want to add/edit
      #server: config/apache/lamp.conf  # Use an alternate apache config file
      #conf: path/from/app/root/php.ini # Alter php configuration with a custom file
  database:  # Create a database server container
    type: mysql
    portforward: 3308
    creds:  # Specify what creds/db to use
      user: drupal8
      password: drupal8
      database: drupal8
  phpmyAdmin:
    type: phpmyadmin
    user: drupal8
    password: drupal8
    database: drupal8
    hosts:
      - mysql57
  mysql57:
    type: mysql:5.7
```

Here is all other database exists except drupal8
[image]

Answer (score 0):

your host in phpMyAdmin services should be the same as the one hosting the database (drupal8):

```
phpmyAdmin:
    type: phpmyadmin
    hosts:
    - drupal8
    mysql57:
    type: mysql:5.7
```

Comment: not sure what this means, there is a lot of "drupal8" in his original file. what exactly are you looking at?